# How GET a list of files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I need that every time I list a portfolio it returns all the images that exist in that specific portfolio
I can list 1 by 1 via ID but when I send my endpoint to list all photos belonging to the ID of a specific portfolio it only returns me null

```
Photo Class
@Entity
public class Foto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String nomeArquivo;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Perfil autonomo;

    @Column(length = 5_000_000)
    private byte[] fotoByte;

    private String tipoArquivo;
}//Getters and Setters
```

AutonomoService

```
   @Autowired
    FotosRepository fotosRepository;

    @Autowired
    PerfisRepository perfisRepository;

    public List<byte[]> portfolio(int id){
        if (perfisRepository.existsById(id)) {
            return fotosRepository.findAllByAutonomoId(id).stream().map(f-> f.getFotoByte()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    } //Getters and Setters
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/portfolio/fotos/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<byte[]>> getPortfolioAutonomo(@PathVariable int id) throws IOException {

    List<byte[]> result = autonomoService.portfolio(id);
    return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(result);
}
```

And this is the way I can get 1 photo by its id

```
 @GetMapping("/portfolio/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity getPortfolio(@PathVariable int id){
        Optional<Foto> anexoOptional = fotosRepository.findById(id);
        if (anexoOptional.isPresent()) {
            Foto anexo = anexoOptional.get();
            return ResponseEntity.status(200)
                    .header("content-type", anexo.getTipoArquivo())
                    .header("content-disposition", "filename=" + anexo.getNomeArquivo())
                    .body(anexo.getFotoByte());
 
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(404).build();
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that perfisRepository.existsById(id) is true?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return fotosRepository.findAllByAutonomoId(id).stream().map(f-> f.getFotoByte()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can you try with

```
return fotosRepository.findAllById(id).stream().map(f-> f.getFotoByte()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If still this is not working, better to go with @Query implemention.